# Axios and Express: Send a request to Express and get responses in multiple steps

Tags: node.js, express, request, axios, response

I'm working on a React/Node program. Somewhere in the program, I want to send a request to back-end using Axios, then while the back-end function is processing the request, I want to get step by step responses to update the front-end by showing some notifications.

I could do this by sending multiple requests and waiting for each response. But the problem is that the first process in each step is identically the same in all steps and it will create some performance issues.

My question is:

Is there any way to send a single request to API, then on the back-end side, return the response in multiple steps while it's processing? Meanwhile on the front-end, get the updates from back-end and update the notifications on it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry bro, I'm afraid that you can't do this with using HTTP alone since the connection is ended with a single response for a single request. You need to do this with multiple HTTP call with Axios.

Otherwise, you could use WebSocket.
Their are cool Module socket.io with planty examples and documentations.
check this out,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io

Comment: I ended up with the exact same procedure and broke the code in different request / responses. Thank you.